# Unterschied zwischen den Wörtern "Plattenfirma" und "Plattenlabel"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, word-choice

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen einem "Plattenlabel" und einer "Plattenfirma"?

Auf Wikipedia findet sich folgende Definition:

Ein Tonträgerunternehmen (umgangssprachlich Plattenfirma) ist ein Unternehmen der Musikindustrie, das die Entwicklung, Produktion und Vermarktung von Musik und ihrer Interpreten auf Tonträgern betreibt.

> Mit Plattenlabel (auch Musiklabel oder kurz Label) wird in der Fachsprache hingegen nur der Organisationsbereich des Tonträgerunternehmes, der die Musiker unter einem bestimmten Markennamen bewirbt und vertreibt, umschrieben. In der Umgangssprache ist oftmals das gesamte Tonträgerunternehmen gemeint.

Verstehe ich das richtig, dass "Plattenlabel" in der Fachsprache also nur die Aufgabe "Vermarktung von Musik und ihrer Interpreten" hat, während der Rest der Plattenfirma die Tonträger produziert (und entwickelt – aber das ist doch eher die Aufgabe der Musiker, oder?)? Und in der Umgangssprache bedeutet "Plattenlabel" dasselbe wie "Plattenfirma"?

Comment: Der Musiker produziert in erster Linie **Töne** - Und die Plattenfirma die **Tonträger**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eine Plattenfirma kann unter einem Label Volksmusik, unter einem anderen Rockmusik und unter einem dritten Klassik vertreiben.

Answer (score 4):

Ein Musiklabel ist nichts anderes als ein Markenname, den ein Unternehmen benutzt, um ihre Produkte (in der Regel Tonträger) zu vermarkten

Vergleiche:

- Unternehmen: Nestlé S.A.

  - Marken: Nescafé, Original-Wagner-Pizza, Friskies, ...
- Unternehmen: Henkel AG & Co. KGaA

  - Marken: Persil, Schwarzkopf, Loctite, ...
- Unternehmen: Universal Music Group

  - Marken (Labels): Virgin Records, Motown Record Company, Deutsche Grammophon, ...